# How to enlarge the clickable of CSS button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I used NavLink for my route, then added some padding, and background color and etc according to the design I want. Then added a border-left style to the active css button to let user easily know where they are. But for some reason I am not able to make the border/background of my css button clickable and, the border-left is only beside of the text instead of the background. Anyone can help me with that?

Here is the css:

```css
.tab-selections {
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    padding: 1.4em 6em;
    height: 1.7em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: .3em;
    vertical-align: top;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(205, 221, 255);
    border-left: .6em solid;
    border-left-color: rgb(87, 0, 255);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is the HTML (ReactJS):

```html
<div className="article container">
      <div className="flex container parent">
        <div className="tab-selections">
          <NavLink
            to="/sample/article"
            style={{ color: '#4b4b4b', textDecoration: 'none' }}
          >
            ARTICLES
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="tab-selections">
          <NavLink
            to="/sample/casestudies"
            style={{ color: '#4b4b4b', textDecoration: 'none' }}
          >
            CASE STUDIES /<br />
            WHITEPAPERS
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="tab-selections">
          <NavLink
            to="/sample/news"
            style={{ color: '#4b4b4b', textDecoration: 'none' }}
          >
            NEWS/EVENTS
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[Here's what the active button looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkdOk.png)

[Here's what it should looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6k1k.png)

Comment: (Aside: we like succinct questions here, and questions are best if they do not contain answers to commentary on the answers. Don't worry about only being able to select one correct answer - choose the one you prefer, and you can upvote any others, though there is no obligation to. It is our way of saying "thanks").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code padding is used to space the container of the NAV-LINK, the solution is instead to apply the padding directly to the NAV-LINK that constitutes your "clickable surface"

so i will change:

```
 style={{ color: '#4b4b4b', textDecoration: 'none' }}
```

to:

```
style={{ color: '#4b4b4b', textDecoration: 'none', padding:  '1.4em 6em'}}
```

however consider to put it inside a css class for better handle

Comment: it actually made the background clickable but the problem is that it will no longer be under a flex. I tried putting "NavLink { css properties..... }" before but it didn't work.

Comment: I understand, as an alternative you could left the padding on nav-link's containers and add to the nav-link some "width:100%; height:100%;" style in order to force them to cover all the space available from the container, in this way the flex behaviour will be mantained

Answer (score 2):

Move `className="tab-selections"` to the `NavLink`, and remove the `div` that wraps the `NavLink` ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l3po0yzwm)):

```
<NavLink
  className="tab-selections"
  to="/sample/article"
  style={{ color: "#4b4b4b", textDecoration: "none" }}
>
  ARTICLES
</NavLink>
```

You should also change the styling a bit, to prevent the text from jumping by adding a transparent border to `.tab-selections`, and change the color when it's active:

```
.tab-selections {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  padding: 1.4em 6em;
  height: 1.7em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.3em;
  vertical-align: top;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
  font-size: 15px;
  border-left: 0.6em solid;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(205, 221, 255);
  border-left-color: rgb(87, 0, 255);
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This is actually made it so much better!

Answer (score 1):

css-wise you need to move your padding rule from `.tab-selections` to your anchor tag. You also need your anchor to be displayed as `block`. Since you are using `<NavLink>` you can add to your inline-style:

`padding: '1.4em 6em', display: 'block'`

So the result becomes:

```
style={{ color: '#4b4b4b', textDecoration: 'none', padding: '1.4em 6em', display: 'block' }}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/b84nvcy0/

Comment: No quotes there.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman you need quotes for the inline-styling, as OP has done.

Comment: Oh okay. That's templating I guess. Ha! React JS.

Comment: It's a React property that accepts a JS object. Let's not split hairs too finely. :)

Comment: @isherwood, hmm? Template literals (I assume that's what Praveen meant) are quite distinct from JS objects.

Comment: by anchor do you mean the parent container? Because my parent container is the ".flex.container.parent"

Comment: @davvid09 I mean the `<a>` tag, which what `<NavLink>` returns.

Comment: @Chris what changed is removed the div and added a classname to my NavLink the result is that the background is now clickable and the active buttons designs are now fixed. There's no need for me to make the "display: block". Which is a good thing for me because the"block" ruins the alignment of text.

Comment: @Chris flex works best for me because one of my css button has a br. The inline-block and block makes the text in css buttons not aligned with the others, from my experience.